# Sobolev regularity required for $|\nabla u|^2 \in H^1(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, sobolev-spaces, regularization

We have $n=2$ and $\Omega=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2\| ||x||_2<1 \}$. I need $|\nabla u|^2 \in H^1(\Omega)$. So i would choose $u \in W^{2,4}(\Omega)$. But since we have $n=2$ I thought that a lower regularization of $u$ is enough.
Probably with Sobolev embedding theorem?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

First we verify that $u\in W^{2,4}$ is sufficient. $|\nabla u |^2\in L^2$ requires $\nabla u\in L^4$ so this means $u\in W^{1,4}$. Then we compute
$$ \partial_i |\nabla u|^2 = 2(\partial_i \nabla u)\cdot\nabla u$$
and we need this to be in $L^2$. Since the strongest constraint so far is $\nabla u\in L^4$ we can use Holder with  $ \frac 12 = \frac14 + \frac14$to bound
$$ \| \nabla |\nabla u|^2\|_{L^2} \le 2 \| \nabla^2 u\|_{L^4} \|\nabla u\|_{L^4}$$
A posteriori, Sobolev embedding tells us that $\nabla u\in W^{1,4}\subset C^{0,\gamma}\subset L^\infty$, which hints that we can use different Holder exponents. In fact, if we assume  $\nabla^2 u\in L^p$ for some $p>n=2$ then we get $\nabla u\in L^\infty$. In which case, we can use Holder with $\frac12 = \frac12 + \frac1\infty$ (and the fact that $\Omega$ is bounded) to see
$$ \| \nabla |\nabla u|^2\|_{L^2} \le 2 \| \nabla^2 u\|_{L^2} \|\nabla u\|_{L^\infty} \le C \| \nabla^2 u\|_{L^p} \|\nabla u\|_{L^\infty}.$$

For $p=n=2$,  it only holds that $\|\nabla u\|_{L^q}\le C_q \|u\|_{H^2}$ for all $q<\infty$, which is not enough, since to use $\|\nabla u\|_{L^q}$ with $q<\infty$ in the Holder estimation, we would need to use $\|\nabla^2 u\|_{L^r}$ with $r>2$.

It follows that the proof also fails when we try $p<2$ (because $L^2 \subset L^p$ on bounded domains).

Summary: $u\in W^{2,p}$ for any $p>2$ is sufficient, as this implies $|\nabla u|^2 \in L^\infty\subset L^2$ and $\nabla|\nabla u|^2\in L^2$.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you this is a great help!

Comment: Somehow the embeddings don't quite fit for me. For $p<d$ holds $W^{k,p} \subset L^q$ according to Gagliardo-Nirenberg-Sobolev for suitable $q$. However, we are in the case $p>d$ and there, according to Morrey, $W^{1,p} \subset C^{0,\gamma}$ for suitable gamma. How do you get your embeddings? Including for $\nabla^2 f \in L^p$ for $p>d$?

Comment: @PeterSo Yes I was using Morrey's inequality, but only through the implication $f\in C^{0,\gamma} \implies f\in L^\infty$. (uniformly continuous on bounded domain is bounded) Does that help?

Comment: Yes that helps already thank you!
But unfortunately I still have a few problems to understand it.
I would write it down once as I have understood it now and try to explain where problems arise.
So we want $|\nabla u|^2 \in H^2(\Omega)$. Accordingly, we need $|\nabla u|^2 \in L^2(\Omega)$ and $\nabla |\nabla u|^2 \in L^2$.
It holds $\partial_i |\nabla u|^2=2(\partial_i \nabla u) \cdot \nabla u$. We achieve this condition if we choose $f \in W^{2,4}$. This would make $\nabla u \in L^4 resp. \nabla u \in W^{1,4}$.

Comment: Now we want to constrain the derivative in the $L^2$norm and by the Hölder inequality and previous findings we obtain  
$||\nabla |\nabla f|||_{L^2(\Omega)}^2  \le 2 ||(\nabla^2 f)^2||_{L^2(\Omega)}||(\nabla f)^2||_{L^2(\Omega)} \le 2||\nabla^2 f||_{L^4(\Omega)}||\nabla f||_{L^4(\Omega)}.$

However, according to Morrey, $W^{1,4}\subset C^{0,\gamma} \subset L^{\infty}$ for $n=2$, since $\Omega$ is a restricted domain. Accordingly, $\nabla u \in W^{1,4}$ is also $\nabla u \in L^{\infty}$. Now I have problems to understand why therefore $\nabla^2 u \in L^p$ for $p>n$ and the hölder unequality.

Comment: @PeterSo, when I wrote "we can obtain A with B" I meant "If we instead assume B, then we can obtain A". So it is not "therefore", but instead exploring the different assumption.

Comment: Thanks i get it!

Comment: @PeterSo Great :) a less clean sufficient condition is $u\in H^2 \cap W^{1,\infty}$ (i.e. it works if you add the assumption that $\nabla u\in L^\infty$)